# can not remove the dotted border from submit button on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using Firefox 27.0.1. I have a third party form that I only have acces to its CSS style, and not to the html code.

I tried to remove the dotted border on the submit button using: `div.submit input[type="submit"] {outline:none;}` but it still appear...

any other way to remove it?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the submit button isn't a `<button type="submit">`?

Comment: Have you used firebug to look at the HTML so you can post out what the markup looks like? It would make telling you how to modify this a lot easier.

Comment: no, it is <input type="submit"...>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers,
what help me to get rid from the dotted border is:

```
    div.submit input[type="submit"]:focus {outline:none;}
    div.submit input[type="submit"]::-moz-focus-inner {border:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a focus event, try this:

```
div.submit input[type="submit"]:focus {
  outline:none;
}
```

Comment: Oh, then can you please tell me, what is the element of that? HTML of the page or just of the button!

Comment: `div.submit input[type="submit"], div.submit input[type="submit"]:focus, div.submit input[type="submit"]:active { outline: none; }`, try setting this property for all the condition of the button!

Comment: just put your code on my css file and firefox still show the dotted.

Comment: Try the `!important` feature of css! I hope that would remove all the hurdles here. Until the issue is the path of the element...

Comment: Can you please give me the HTML of your form or whatever this is? Create a fiddle please.. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: see link for my page: view-source:https://www.visa-usa.co.il/%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%92%D7%A9%D7%AA-%D7%98%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA/#gf_1#gf_1#gf_1#gf_1

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have 'focus' inside your CSS file which focuses the item as a dotted.

Comment: The only 'focus' I have in my css file is:  div.submit input[type="submit"]:focus {
  outline:none;
}

Comment: Add 'outline:none !important;'  Perhaps some other value above it eliminates its working.